# String Arrays (String[ ]) are printing out in a single line despite println

Tags: java, format

When I am printing out questions[0] into a TextArea, the output looks like this:

> Line1Line2

I want the output to looks like this:

> Line1
>
> Line2

Despite using `println` How do I change the format of the output?

The Code:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            write = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            //Skriva till klienten.
            List<String> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();

            try (Stream<String> questionsStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(quizFile))) {  //Reading from text file
                questionsList = questionsStream
                        .parallel()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                Collections.shuffle(questionsList);  //Randomizing the Strings.

                while (true) {

                    for (String string : questionsList) {
                        String[] questions = string.split("/");
                        write.println(questions[0]);  //Printing out [0]."\n" does not seperate the String to seperate lines.
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(4000); //"Sleeping" between the lines.
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This looks like a problem on the client side. You should show the receiver side instead. If text is displayed as HTML, add '<br>' after each line,

Comment: Do your strs in `questionsList` have text with `/` symbol?

Comment: @Axel: The OP says this is outputting to a `textarea`; if so, the line breaks are sufficient. Using `<br>` would actually put the text `<br>` in the `textarea`.

Comment: We need to see what's actually going to the client browser. When you run your code, use View Source (Ctrl+U on most browsers) or the Network panel in the dev tools to see what your server *actually* sent.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think there are dozens of TextArea implementations out there. There's one in AWT, another in JavaFX, then HTML and who knows what.  OP should specify what he is using on the client.

Comment: @Axel You solved it for me! I hade no line break "\n" in the client! Please post a short answer so I can thank you properly =)

Answer (score 0):

you should use HTML, tag '
'in to`write.println(questions[0] + "<br>");` .

Comment: No, the OP says this is outputting to a `textarea`; if so, the line breaks are sufficient. Using `<br>` would actually put the text `<br>` in the `textarea`.